# Add Azure AD group to Azure DevOps group fails with 500

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

This script used to work 3-4 months ago when I last tested. But lately this has been failing. Can anyone suggest what might be the issue? I am adding an AAD group to an ADO group. But this gives a 500 error with no explanation of the issue. I have verified that the ADO group descriptor and the AAD group Guid are correct.

```
$OrganizationName = "mycompany"
$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)"))}
$groupDescriptor = "vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1<Something>"
$projectAdminAADGroupID = "4409bada-<someguid>"
$uriAddADGroupToADOGroup = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/_apis/graph/groups?groupDescriptors=$($groupDescriptor)&api-version=6.1-preview.1"
$groupConfig = @{"originId"= "$($projectAdminAADGroupID)"} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAddADGroupToADOGroup -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Body $groupConfig -ContentType "application/json"
```

However I keep getting a Http 500 error. I know for sure that this worked without any issue in the past.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Comment: Is Basic auth still supported?? Either way are you sure there is no body returned?

Comment: I believe the authentication works. I can do other operations like a GET and get a list of groups, etc.

The response is as follows -
Internal system error when processing the request for the page
(&nbsp;https://vssps.dev.azure.com/XXXX/_apis/graph/groups?groupDescriptors=vssgp.Uy0xLTktYYYYYYYYYYYYYY#038;api-version=6.1-preview.1&nbsp;).
Username:
Source IP: <machine IP>
URL: POST https://vssps.dev.azure.com/XXXX/_apis/graph/groups?groupDescriptors=vssgp.Uy0xLTYYYYYYY#038;api-version=6.1-preview.1
Category: URL Filtering Bypassed
Reason: UNKNOWN
Notification: INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: Your script works fine from my side. If your ADO group descriptor and the AAD group Guid are correct, I think the issue should lie in the backend service side.

Comment: Is there any way to get more information from the response? A 500 doesn't tell much unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to be related to Conditional Access Policies that were causing a failure to retrieve a token. We excluded the service account from the CAP and the calls worked.